# Сountry names are not displayed on the map

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis

I`m trying to create map which has several layers. One of them consist of country borders (admin_level = 2,3), country name and region names.
I use data of coordinates of Armenia and China from https://download.geofabrik.de/asia.html.
I succesfully consolidated these countries with Osmosis 0.40.1.:

```
osmosis --read-pbf armenia-latest.osm.pbf --read-pbf china-latest.osm.pbf --merge --write-pbf ArChina.osm.pbf
```

And extracted border with admin_level = 2,3:

```
osmosis --read-pbf ArChina.osm.pbf --tf accept-relation boundary=administrative admin_level=2,3 --tf reject-ways admin_level=5,6,7,8,9 --used-way idTrackerType=Dynamic --tf reject-nodes admin_level=4,5,6,7,8,9 --tf reject-nodes place=village,town,suburb,city --used-node idTrackerType=Dynamic --write-xml ArChinaBord1.osm
```

Then I converted it to .osm.pbf with Osmosis.

I understand that I didn't remove all the nodes such as bus stops, natural objects, etc. That`s not the problem.

The problem is - when I`ve launched this map on Ubuntu server - I saw the borders of 2 countries, region names of both of them and only 1 country name (Armenia). I was trying to zoom in and zoom out, but it didn't help. Сhina name is not showing at all.

I checked  ArChinaBord1.osm (consolidated file with Armenia and China borders, names). The xml structure of Armenia and China names (node with place=country) is the same, but only one name is shown.

Could you give me some advice, how it could be fixed?

Comment: crosspost: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73797449/%d0%a1ountry-names-are-not-displayed-on-the-map

Answer (score 0):

To check that what relations are in your output .pbf, perhaps create an easily greppable file with osmium, something like:

```
osmium cat -o foo.opl foo.osm.pbf
```

(opl is a "one per line" text file).

Unfortunately this won't tell you that any relations are valid and don't (say) have missing bits.  If you load a Postgres database** with the resulting .pbf and something that should be an area turns up in the planet_osm_line table instead of planet_osm_polygon, it's not a valid polygon in the converted data that you are trying to load.

** See one of the options [here](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/), but only worry about loading the database, not about rendering tiles from it.

Comment: Thanks. The problem was solved by adding admin level 4 borders on the map.